# Sentry Sourcemaps Uploading in Development But Not Production

Tags: webpack, sentry

I am trying to upload source maps to Sentry and I notice that I can only get them to upload when I build webpack in development mode and can not get them to upload when I run build webpack in production mode.

I feel like it has something to do with building webpack in dev mode outputs the files to the dir while running webpack in production mode does not output the build files to the dir. The dir sent in output.path is empty for a production build but not a dev build.

This is the CMD lines I run

Dev:
`UPLOAD_SOURCE_MAP=true NODE_ENV=production && webpack --mode production -d source-map`

Dev:
`npm ci --legacy-peer-deps && NODE_ENV=development && UPLOAD_SOURCE_MAP=true webpack --mode development -d inline-source-map --watch`

My webpack.config.mjs file:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import TsconfigPathsPlugin from 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin';
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import { sentryWebpackPlugin } from "@sentry/webpack-plugin";

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/webroot/js/react_build');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/react/components');

const config = {
    entry: {
        reactvendors: { import: ['react', 'react-dom'] },
        LoginHistory: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Login_History/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        MarketingExpense: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Marketing_Expense/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        MetricDrillDown: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Metric_Drill_Down/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        MyDashboard: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/My_Dashboard/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        OrderHistory: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Order_History/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        ProgressGraphs: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Progress_Graphs/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
        WorkoutForm: {
            import: `${APP_DIR}/Workout_Form/render.tsx`,
            dependOn: 'reactvendors',
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'chunk-[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: '/js/react_build/',
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/,
                    `${APP_DIR}/app/react/components/**/*.test.tsx`
                ],
                include: APP_DIR,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    [
                                        "autoprefixer",
                                    ],
                                ],
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.scss'],
    },
    plugins: [].concat(
        process.env.UPLOAD_SOURCE_MAP ?
            sentryWebpackPlugin({
                org: "the-perfect-workout",
                project: "react-athena",

                // Auth tokens can be obtained from https://sentry.io/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/
                // and need `project:releases` and `org:read` scopes
                authToken: 'removed for stack overflow',
            }) : []
    )
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your command is broken with `&&` placed wrong.

Try without `&&`: `UPLOAD_SOURCE_MAP=true NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production -d source-map`